# "sh: sysctl Command not Found " for Mac OS X running a cron job

Tags: python, macos, terminal, cron

I have a python script, `script.py`, and am using cron to run this script periodically. The script runs as expected, but once the cron job finishes, I get the following error in /var/mail/[myusername]:

`sh: sysctl   Command Not Found`

The following is the cron job:

```
0 14  * * * PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin PYTHONPATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ /usr/bin/python2.7 ~/.../script.py
```

I was told to include both PATH and PYTHONPATH in the task (as before, python wouldn't recognize several modules I had imported and had installed), so at this point, I'm not sure what the problem could be

Comment: on some Macs apparently `sysctl` is located in `/sbin/` instead of `/usr/sbin/`. Try adding `/sbin` to your PATH variable

Comment: In my ~/.bash_profile, my path variable is as follows:

`PATH=PATH="$HOME/sbin/:$PATH"
export PATH`

And I'm still getting the error... Am I simply not adding PATH correctly?

Comment: Well you don't want it to be `$HOME/sbin/` because `$HOME` is `/Users/<username>` not the root directory `/`. So the short answer is yes, you're not adding PATH correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much! This fixed it!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On some Macs, `sysctl` is located in `/sbin/` instead of `/usr/sbin/`. You should add `/sbin` to your `PATH` variable